# Chapter names from terminal

Tags: chapters, mac, terminal-output

Is there out of the box way how to list chapters of Book document from terminal via MacTex? I want to keep list of chapters somewhere aside from the actual chapter files. Like one independent plaintext file with just chapter names.

I am hoping for just some flag to latex or some external analyzer. My desire was inspired by --list-tags from Ansible. It just gathers all the tags and spits them out. I don't want to polute the document files with some stuff for things outside of it.

Comment: What format should this list have?

Comment: a bit simpler could be to just `grep -h '\\chapter' file.tex`.

Comment: @morbusg Yes, and then some `sed s/(\\chapter{|})//g`. I was thinking about it and I have it as last resort. I would have to solve sorting of the chapters also :/

Answer (score 4):

This will produce a `.lch` file in the format shown below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@schapter}
 {{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo\addtocontents{lch}{#1//}}}
 {}{}
\xapptocmd{\@chapter}
 {\addtocontents{lch}{#2//\thechapter}}
 {}{}
\newwrite\tf@lch
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\openout\tf@lch=\jobname.lch}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter*{Introduction}

\chapter{Foo}

\chapter{Foob\r{a}r}

\end{document}
```

This is what's written out:

```
Contents//
Introduction//
Foo//1
Foob\r {a}r//2
```

Unnumbered chapters will have nothing after `//` (or `0` if `\chapter` is used in the front matter).

Changing the output format is quite easy.

---

How does this work?

First we add some code to be executed at every `\@schapter` (for `\chapter*)` and `\@chapter` command. The code is essentially

```
\addtocontents{lch}{<chapter title>//<chapter number}
```

with an adjustment for `\@schapter` in order not to get header information from `\@mkboth`.

The instruction `\addtocontents{lch}{<tokens>}` will write

```
\@writefile{lch}{<tokens>}
```

in the `.aux` file.

The kernel `\@writefile{<string>}{<tokens>}` command changes its definition at end document, when the `.aux` file is read for the second time. Its job becomes:

> if an output stream named `tf@<string>` is open, write on it `<tokens>` (with `\protected@write`).

Therefore we also open the stream `\tf@lch` and let LaTeX do its normal job.

Comment: I was hoping for just some flag to latex or some external analyzer. My desire was inspired by --list-tags from Ansible. It just gather all the tags and spits them out. I don't want to polute the document files with some stuff for things outside of it.

Answer (score 3):

This writes the names of the chapters (without numbers), one after another one, line by line, to the `\jobname.chap` file, by adding the `\immediate\write{}`  statement.

It should work on any OS since writing to files is a 'must' when dealing with LaTeX (which tries to write the `.log` and `.aux` files at least, unless `\nofiles` is enabled)

If there is more than just text content in the chapter name, this approach will fail unless `\protected@write` is used:

```
\documentclass{book}

%Eventually morewrites package if there too many file handles
%\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newwrite\chapnames

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
}{%
  \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
  \protected@write\chapnames{}{#2^^J}%
}{}{}
\makeatother


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \immediate\openout\chapnames=\jobname.chap
}

\AtEndDocument{% Close the file
  \closeout\chapnames% Do not close prematurely, so no \immediate here!
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}

\chapter{Foobar \textbf{foo}}% Not recommended to use such stuff like `\textbf{...}` anyway here
\end{document}
```

**Update** Cleaner version -- Use `\writechapnamestrue` or `\writechapnamesfalse` to enable or disable the writing of chapter names to the file.

```
\documentclass{book}

% Eventually morewrites package if there too many file handles
%\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{xparse}


\newwrite\chapnames
\newif\ifwritechapnames

\makeatletter
\let\latex@@chapter\chapter

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \latex@@chapter*{#3}%
  }{%
    \latex@@chapter[#2]{#3}%
  }%
  \ifwritechapnames
  \protected@write\chapnames{}{#3}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \immediate\openout\chapnames=\jobname.chap
}

\AtEndDocument{% Close the file
  \closeout\chapnames% Do not close prematurely, so no \immediate here!
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\writechapnamestrue

\chapter[Bar]{Bar stuff}
\chapter{Foo}

\chapter{Foobar \textbf{foo}}% Not recommended to use such stuff like `\textbf{...}` anyway here
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was hoping for just some flag to latex or some external analyzer. My desire was inspired by --list-tags from Ansible. It just gather all the tags and spits them out. I don't want to polute the document files with some stuff for things outside of it.

Comment: @Mailo: Thanks for complaining -- your question did not say anything about external analyzing tools, did it? ;-)

Comment: christian: It was not meant as complaining. More like making the direction I want to go more clear. When you refer to my original question, I hope You noticed the part "out of the box" and when you refer to my comment to your answer, I am mentioning "some external analyzer" as OR -- ANOTHER option. Your answer is pretty detailed, which shows that You spent some time on it, hence I understand Your frustration from me not being happy with it. It just doesn't apply to what I want to do, sorry.